# New control button doesn't have the correct Windows ID

Tags: c++, winapi, button, controls

I have a Window form application in C++.
I added a new button and linked it to a function called `ChangeTitle`.

But when I run the application and I press the button, it doesn't call the function.
I checked and I noticed that when I click the button and check the Window ID of the button (`wmId`), which I set it to be `110` (`IDM_CHANGE_TITLE`), it is with the value of `1`.

I am not sure what is the problem, maybe it is related to the resource file?

**Reproduce:**

Open Visual Studio and
Create new project `Visual C++` -> `Windows Desktop Application`.
Set it with the name `WindowsProject1`.

**Code of WindowsProject1.cpp**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK ChangeTitle(HWND hWnd);

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            case IDM_CHANGE_TITLE:
                ChangeTitle(hWnd);
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindowW(L"button", L"Change Title",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
            20, 50, 95, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)1, (HINSTANCE)ChangeTitle(hWnd), NULL);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK ChangeTitle(HWND hWnd)
{
   SetWindowText(hWnd, L"BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");
   return TRUE;
}
```

**Part code of Resource.h**

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by WindowsProject1.rc

#define IDM_ABOUT               104
#define IDM_CHANGE_TITLE                110
```

**Part code of WindowsProject1.rc**

```
IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1 MENU
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&About ...",           IDM_ABOUT
    END
END

IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1 ACCELERATORS
BEGIN
    "?",            IDM_ABOUT,              ASCII,  ALT
    "/",            IDM_ABOUT,              ASCII,  ALT
END
```

Comment: Are you sure you set window ID as `IDM_CHANGE_TITLE`? I just Ctrl-F'd in the page for that, and altogether it appears twice: one is `#define` and the other `case IDM_CHANGE_TITLE:`

Comment: Yes, I set it like that `#define IDM_CHANGE_TITLE 110` and then I used it in `case IDM_CHANGE_TITLE:`, did I miss something?

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable I attached code snippets. To reproduce it you need to create a "Windows Desktop Application" and copy the code I added.

Comment: Why don't you create a [mcve] instead? Do we need to see your *About* dialog? Do we need to see your main menu? Do we need to see any of your string table entries? Do we need a *Resource.h* with all sorts of IDE management noise? All of that is unrelated to the issue. Strip it down to is **bare minimum**.

Comment: @IInspectable I can do it, but it's hard with C++. I will need to upload it to GitHub and update you once it ready.

Comment: Do **not** link to an off-site resource. Instead, create a [mcve], **in the question itself**. It's no harder with C++ than it is with C, Go, Rust, JavaScript, or any other language. If you do not understand the anatomy of a Windows application, get some reference material. Petzold's [Programming Windows](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X) is pretty much required reading.

Comment: @IInspectable okay, I understand what you meant. I modified the code, now it should be easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that I created the button control with `hMenu` set to `1`.
I changed it to `#define IDM_CHANGE_TITLE   110` and now it works.
Here is the fixed code:

```
CreateWindowW(L"button", L"Change Title",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
    20, 50, 95, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)IDM_CHANGE_TITLE, NULL, NULL);
```